# bentorfs angular bootstrap multiselect: multiple display-prop

Tags: angular, multi-select

Our team is using [bentorf's angular bootstrap multiselect](http://bentorfs.github.io/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/) and it works great, but we're wondering if we can add more display-props.  Right now we just have Names show up in the multiselect drop down, but ideally we would want other items to show up as well (e.g. position, department, etc.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It supports [Objects as model](http://bentorfs.github.io/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/#example-objects) and a `display-prop` input so instead of passing a list of name strings, you should pass a list of model objects and set `display-prop` to your model's getter attribute.

Let's say `display-prop="fullName"` for example. Then you define the getter in your model class like:

```
class Employee {
    private name: string;
    private department: string;

    get fullName(): string {
        return `Name: ${this.name} | Dept: ${this.department}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @tianissimo!  So instead of an array of names, I've populated an object array that includes name, location, department, and a key called "fullInfo" with the concatenation of name + location + department as the value.  Is this what you're suggesting?  Thanks!